# Как передать сообщение по RTP при потоковом аудиосигнале

Tags: python, voip, rtp

Здравствуйте, мне надо связать два устройства по RTP, телефон и микроконтроллер по типу ip-телефонии дома через роутер. При этом с телефона надо в момент разговора послать команду на микроконтроллер. Можно ли это сделать?

Comment: А сигнальный протокол какой? SIP? Команду по нему удобней послать будет. (DTMF например)

Comment: хм, по идеи RTP (или это разные вещи, я просто не до конца здесь еще разбираюсь), для микроконтроллера есть либа для RTP...

Comment: и как это тогда сделать на питоне?

Comment: Я хз (иначе я бы написал полноценный ответ), но я точно знаю что протокол RTP не имеет механизмов для самостоятельного установления сессии, эта задачу выполняют протоколы сигнализации, такие как SIP, H.323, SCCP. И произвольную команду можно передать по ним. Копайте в ту сторону.